# How to restrict lead records when i change the status field?

Tags: leads, field-level-security, owd

I am creating two users A and B using salesforce profiles. when user A create lead with status open it will show Admin user,User A and User B. Now my requirement is User A changed the status is prospect, it will not show to User B.so, How to retrict the record field value when i change to prospect. can you pls give me any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Since, both the users A and B, share the same profile, so Field level security will not work here.

Both the users can view the field. Only way to restrict record field value when you change to prospect, is to use **Validation Rule**.

Comment: pls give me example

Comment: create a validation rule and throw the error during save. If you face any issues then edit your question with issues.

Comment: Your way is showing error,when i edit and change the status of particular record. but my requirement is user 'A' do not show the lead status of user 'B'.